# Can "Mar adentro" have a double meaning?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, significado

There's a movie called "Mar adentro", and I wonder, whether this phrase can actually mean two things simultaneously (which would be so cool):

1) Inside the sea

2) The sea inside

Or is it just one of the above?

Comment: i don't think this comment deserves to be an answer but the meanings for me are : 

"deep in the sea" and "deep inside", the "mar adentro" is when you go so deep in the see that you can't see the land anymore

Comment: The movie title is translated as The Sea Inside. That is truly awful; We would say; The Sea Within. In the sea in Spanish would be: en el mar. We would not say in English either: the sea inside or inside the sea. The sea is not a container in that sense in English. This means you have a sea within you, literarily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. According to the DRAE's definition of [adentro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0jInJpU)

> 1. adv. A o en lo interior. *Mar adentro, tierra adentro. Se metió por las puertas adentro.*
> 2. m. pl. Lo interior del ánimo. *Hablo para mis adentros. Juan habla bien de Pedro, aunque en sus adentros siente de otro modo.*

It can mean both "en lo interior (de algo)" (inside) or "interior del ánimo" (within), meaning, what we consider inside us, not physically, but metaphorically.

So "mar adentro" can have both meanings or interpretations (*inside the sea* and *the sea within/inside*). The first one is even one of the examples in the dictionary.

> Debemos ir *mar adentro* y echar las redes
>
> Tengo un mar de dudas adentro de mi

Probably is more common to use "interior" for this second meaning, but definitely you can use "adentro".

Comment: This came as a surprise to me; indeed, I fully agree with Diego. I just want to add that a better translation of the second meaning would be the “sea within”. That captures the idea better.

Comment: mar adentro would be: out at sea, away from the coast. Tierra adentro is inland. mar adentro: out at sea. Not on the coast. Costa abajo: down the hill.

Comment: Right, mar adentro is the sea within or out at sea. Both inside the sea and the sea inside are really English mistakes. So, I have to agree with this answer.

Comment: Debemos ir mar adentro y echar las redes: we should go out to sea and set out our nets.

Comment: Thanks for the note, the question basically shows my disastrous level of English.

Comment: @mxgrn on the contrary, the point I wanted to make is that you correctly sensed a subtlety that I would miss out of familiarity with the first interpretation...